# how to change key value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

```
my_dict = {
    'k1': 1,
    'k2': 2,
    'k3': 3,
    'k4': 4

}
```

Hi how to change the key value to K11 , K21 , K31 ..i am receiving run time error when try to change the key names

Comment: Hi! Please add the full code and the corresponding error. But just create a new key with the value from the old one and delete the old one

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```py
new_dict = {}

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    new_dict[k + '1'] = v

print(new_dict)
```

Output: `{'k11': 1, 'k21': 2, 'k31': 3, 'k41': 4}`

If you want the changes to be applied to my_dict, just add the line `my_dict = new_dict`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use a dict comprehension:

```py
new_dict = {k+"1": v for (k, v) in my_dict.items()}
```